# A method to print a binary search tree (BST) from the largest element to the smallest

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I think I have to modify one of the traversals. I tried modifying one that print from the smallest to the largest which is this one

```
private void printTree(BinaryTreeNode t) {
    if (t != null) {
        printTree(t.llink);
        System.out.print(" " + t.info);
        printTree(t.rlink);
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. I'm still stuck on what I should try next. This the binary search tree I'm using:

```
public class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {
    //Default constructor.
    //Postcondition: root = null;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        super();
    }

    //Copy constructor.
    public BinarySearchTree(BinarySearchTree otherTree) {
        super(otherTree);
    }

public class BinaryTree {

    //Definition of the node
    protected class BinaryTreeNode {

        DataElement info;
        BinaryTreeNode llink;

        public DataElement getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode getLlink() {
            return llink;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode getRlink() {
            return rlink;
        }
        BinaryTreeNode rlink;
    }

    protected BinaryTreeNode root;

    //Default constructor
    //Postcondition: root = null;
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    //Copy constructor
    public BinaryTree(BinaryTree otherTree) {
        if (otherTree.root == null) //otherTree is empty.
        {
            root = null;
        }
        else {
            root = copy(otherTree.root);
        }
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, is swapping the two attributes really such a challenge?

Comment: @Tudor it didn't work man I tried it and I didn't, and @ Niklas no its not and if you read what I wrote above you would've saw that I tried that instead of trying to be a smartass man just read my question first.

Comment: @hws: Ok, but what problem are you encountering? Wrong results? Exceptions? Can you be more more specific? Can you post the tree you are using to test?

Comment: The error my friend is it print the elements but it doesn't print them from largest to smallest, hope that's clear enough, and to the binary tree I'm using I posted the code above.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted looks OK for sorting from smallest to largest.

If you want to sort the other way around, then the following code should work:

```
private void printTree(BinaryTreeNode t) {
        if (t != null) {
            printTree(t.rlink);
            System.out.print(" " + t.info);
            printTree(t.llink);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the code you put it didn't do the trick it still doesn't print from largest to smallest using that code.

Comment: Could it be that your BinaryTree is not a BST, by any chance?

Comment: Nah I'm really sure about it, and it works when I use it to print from smallest to largest

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do it swap the llink and rlink. To print the tree from largest to smallest, you  can use one of the trees traversal methods. for example, the one that suits this case is the Inorder traversal because it prints the tree from smallest to largest in terms of values. All you have to do is the following:

```
if(t!=null){        
    printTree(t.rlink);
    System.out.print(" " + t.info);
    printTree(t.llink);
}
```

That should print it from largest to smallest.

Comment: Just like @Hakan Serce proposed.